# Como resolver esse conflito de encode no php?

Tags: php, utf-8

Pessoal tenho a rotina abaixo que faz a listagem de arquivos de um diretório:

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {

    $dh = opendir($dir);

    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

        if (!in_array($file, array(".", ".."))) {

            $html->NOMEARQ = utf8_encode($file);
            $html->DATAARQ = date("d/m/Y", filemtime($dir . $file));
            $html->TAMANHO = fGetNumero(filesize($dir . $file) / 1000) . " KB";
            $html->LINKARQ = "/arquivos/arquivos.download?p=docs&f=" . utf8_encode($file);

            $html->block("BLOCK_LISTAGEM");

            $qtdarq++;
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
```

Acontece que minha maquina de desenvolvimento é Windows10 com Apache, e o Servidor é Ubuntu com Apache, na minha maquina ele lê normalmente os nomes de arquivos com caracteres especiais, ÇÃO á é etc...

Mas quando coloco em produção no Ubuntu/Apache tenho que retirar a função utf8_encode senão ele bagunça todo o nome do arquivo.

Sei que isso ocorre porque o windows e linux tratam diferente os nomes de arquivos me parece que o windows usa ANSI e o Linux UTF8.

Existe uma forma de tratar isso sem que eu tenha que modificar meu codigo PHP ao colocar no servidor?

Não posso modificar os nomes dos arquivos, retirar os acentos e afins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é verificar o servidor:

```
if (stripos(php_uname('s'), 'win') === 0) {
   $html->NOMEARQ = utf8_encode($file);
} else {
   $html->NOMEARQ = $file;
}
```

Outra alternativa, é forçar enviando o `header` como o colega sugeriu na outra resposta.

Comment: Nossa cara tenho que fazer essa verificação, pois só setando com UTF-8 não adianta... esse lance de encode é um saco, rsrsrs

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou isso definir o encoding padrão do PHP?

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: Meus arquivos já são UTF-8 e ainda assim coloco o set pra isso, mas nessa listagem de arquivos está dando esse problema, tenho que setar no ambiente desenvolvimento e retirar no ambiente produção... é um saco isso, as vezes passa batido, ai la vai o usuario reclamar, rsrsrs, mas a gente acostuma.

Answer (score 0):

Sem modificar o php não sei, mas modificando pode ser que isto resolva. Testei aqui, num ubuntu/apache, experimente definir o header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Ou, em vez de utf8_encode, faça o [oposto](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

```
utf8_decode($file);
```

Testei com ficheiros/diretórios com caracteres especiais e [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), esta ultima resultou

Vi também esta solução. Caso esteja em php6, experimente mudar o php.ini:

```
unicode_semantics = On
```

Comment: Já estou usando a função encode e decode, queria fazer algo mais amigável, mas pelo jeito vai ter que ser POG mesmo